# Volume Discount Issue

Tags: sql-server, volume

Assume the following problem Disc =0 qty1=20 qty1disc5  qty2=22 qty2disc=7 qty3=24 qty3disc=9 qty4 =26 qty4disc=11 qty5=30 qty5disc=13
the below works for that senario but assume the customer decideds to only goto 2 level and qty3-qty5 =0 I need the system acknowledge qty is the max and that is the discount applied. If the discount field has a value the volumne discount does not applied its ignored

```
DECLARE @qty INT = 24;

SELECT        tblCustomerSpecialsSet.tblCustomerSpecials_tblCustomer, tblCustomerSpecialDetailsSet.tblCustomerSpecialDetails_tblProducts,
       tblCustomerSpecialDetailsSet.Price,

   
   case 
   when    tblCustomerSpecialDetailsSet.Disc <> 0 then tblCustomerSpecialDetailsSet.Disc

   when  @qty >= qty1  AND @qty < qty2 then qty1DiscPerc
   when @qty >= qty2)   and @qty < qty3 then  qty2DiscPerc 
   when  @qty >= qty3  and @qty < qty4 then  qty3DiscPerc 
   when  @qty >= qty4 and @qty < qty5 then qty3DiscPerc 
   when @qty >= qty5 then qty5DiscPerc
  
  
  
  else 0
   end  as disc,
   
   tblTaxes.TaxPercentage,tblProductsSet.Cost 
   FROM            tblCustomerSpecialsSet INNER JOIN 
    tblCustomerSpecialDetailsSet ON tblCustomerSpecialsSet.Id = tblCustomerSpecialDetailsSet.tblCustomerSpecialDetails_tblCustomerSpecials INNER JOIN 
  tblProductsSet ON tblCustomerSpecialDetailsSet.tblCustomerSpecialDetails_tblProducts = tblProductsSet.Id INNER JOIN 
   tblTaxes ON tblProductsSet.tblProducts_tblTax = tblTaxes.Id 
   WHERE        (tblCustomerSpecialsSet.tblCustomerSpecials_tblCustomer = 6311) AND (tblCustomerSpecialDetailsSet.tblCustomerSpecialDetails_tblProducts =9604) `
```

Comment: Please supply sample input and output data. As it is, it's hard to work out what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

Just confirming - in some instances, you may not have all the 'levels' of discount, so you don't want to go to all the levels?

Those amounts and discounts come from a table listing the amount needed to get that discount.

For example, you may have two items

```
Item# | qty1_amt qty1_disc | qty2_amt qty2_disc | qt3_amt qt3_disc
1     | 5        10        | 10       20        | 15      33
2     | 5        10        | 10       20        | NULL    NULL
```

If someone bought 20 of each item

- They would get a discount of 33% on Item# 1, as it's above qt3_amt
- They would only get a discount of 20% on Item# 2 as that's as high as it goes

If the above is true, then I think you are almost there in your approach.

However, what you need to do, when determining a level of discount, is also check if the *next* level of discount is unavailable. If it's unavailable, then take the current level.

```
case 
   when tblCustomerSpecialDetailsSet.Disc <> 0 then tblCustomerSpecialDetailsSet.Disc

   when @qty >= qty1 AND (@qty < qty2 OR qty2 IS NULL) then qty1DiscPerc
   when @qty >= qty2 AND (@qty < qty3 OR qty3 IS NULL) then qty2DiscPerc 
   when @qty >= qty3 AND (@qty < qty4 OR qty4 IS NULL) then qty3DiscPerc 
   when @qty >= qty4 AND (@qty < qty5 OR qty5 IS NULL) then qty4DiscPerc 
   when @qty >= qty5 then qty5DiscPerc

   else 0
   end
```

Watch out by the way - you have a few typos in your code above (e.g., extra brackets, qty4DiscPerc is written as qty3DiscPerc, etc).